# React/Flux - error propagation from action to store/component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

This is a question about error propagation from react/flux actions into the store and then back to the component, the error is not validation, rather its an api call failure when trying to update the state of the store.

Here is a pretty simple example:

Component:

```
CityList.jsx
    list of cities is held in a field thats bound to store data field, - This loops over these and writes list of City.jsx:

City.jsx
    Populates the city data to the user, including a toggle button to say whether they have visited or not, e.g:

    name: {this.state.city.name}
    country: {this.state.city.country}
    visited: {this.state.city.visited}
```

Toggling the 'visited' button fires a 'toggleVisited' action with that city object:

```
Actions:
    CityActions.js
        toggleVisited(city)
        Takes a city object, makes a request to the api to update the 'visited' value and pushes result to store

Store:
    CityStore.js
        onToggleVisited(city)
        Receives city object from the action and updates the relevant item in its cities array with new value
```

Now what happens when the api called in the CityActions returns an error? How do I map that to the correct component to show the appropriate error messages (red border, error text etc) to indicate that the update failed?

My initial thought was to set an error field on the city object after the api call in the action, then set it back in the store looking something like this:

```
{
    name: '',
    country: '',
    visited: '',
    error: true
}
```

(error could be an object) Then the component would re-render the city and

so then the component could read the error field and show the relevant error messages when its rendered.

So:

- Is there a better way to handle these errors?
- If I wanted to show a global error at the top of the page, theres no
  way to know without looping through the data to check for at least
  one instance of {error: true} and then render the error - this is not
  ideal.
- Is there any way to map errors to components?

Answer (score 0):

To render a global error on top of the page, you could store a global error message in the CityStore.
When the response from the API contains error, you update the global error object in CityStore.
When the view then gets the state from CityStore, you don't need to loop over all cities to check for an error.

You could still keep the `error: true` in the city object itself, e.g. if you also want to highlight some city in the view that has the actual error.